# Angular CLI Project Missing Module Errors After Git Pull

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using Angular4 with Angular/CLI 1.2.1. I'm able to initialize fine and use ng serve to run the application locally. However, after pushing to a remote git repo and then doing pulling my work down on a different machine - I get errors.

**Steps to Recreate**
1. Pull project created using Angular CLI from remote git repo.
2. NPM install.
3. ng serve.

**Error Messages**

> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.component.ts (1,27): Cannot find
>   module '@angular/core'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.component.ts (8,14): Experimental
>   support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a
>   future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this
>   warning.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.module.ts (1,31): Cannot find
>   module '@angular/platform-browser'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.module.ts (2,26): Cannot find
>   module '@angular/core'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.module.ts (16,14): Experimental
>   support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a
>   future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this
>   warning.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/main.ts (1,32): Cannot find module
>   '@angular/core'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/main.ts (2,40): Cannot find module
>   '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
>
> ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/main.ts (1,32): Cannot find module
>   '@angular/core'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/main.ts (2,40): Cannot find module
>   '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.module.ts (1,31): Cannot find
>   module '@angular/platform-browser'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.module.ts (2,26): Cannot find
>   module '@angular/core'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.module.ts (16,14): Experimental
>   support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a
>   future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this
>   warning.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.component.ts (1,27): Cannot find
>   module '@angular/core'.
>
> ERROR in D:/application/src/app/app.component.ts (8,14): Experimental
>   support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a
>   future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this
>   warning.
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

**NPM Install Output**

npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@4.5.3 install D:\application\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.5.3\win32-x64-48_binding.node

> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall D:\application\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

Binary found at D:\application\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine

...proceeds to install without error (including @angular/core and other packages).

Comment: The errors indicate that angular is missing in your node_modules directory (or that node_modules itself is missing). What is the output of `npm install`?

Comment: Added NPM Install output above. No errors.

Comment: Update your angular libraries to latest and try running ng serve after that

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to remove node_modules folder from your angular project hierarchy and use to re install all the packages by using npm install

Answer (score 0):

go to the project folder in your terminal and type `npm rebuild`.

If your node_modules doesn't exist or doesn't have all the dependencies needed, delete and run `npm install`.

Refer to this thread: [How to run "npm install" to create node_modules folder for an older Angular project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475861/how-to-run-npm-install-to-create-node-modules-folder-for-an-older-angular-proj)

Answer (score 0):

try Deleting package-lock.json file and then install node_modules npm install