# How to run "npm install" to create node_modules folder for an older Angular project?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm pulling our code down from our repository to a new laptop.  Our project was built on Angular 5 last year.  Of course, the new laptop has the latest and greatest Angular CLI, NodeJS, and NPM tools install, and Angular 6 was just released. The laptop has Node 8.11.2, NPM 5.6.0, and Angular CLI 6.0.3.

When I run "npm install" to get the "node_modules" folder on my new laptop for this project, I'm getting all kinds of errors and warnings and unable to create the node_modules folder successfully[image] (see image attached). What can I do to get this project running.  I don't necessarily care about upgrading to Angular 6 at this time.  I simply need to continue to be able to run and develop this project.

Our package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --environment=local --open",
    "build": "ng build --prod aot=false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngui/map": "^0.20.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "google-maps-coords": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules and execute `npm install`

Comment: Try running `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm cache clean` and do `npm install`

Comment: @Vikas, yes, that's what I'm trying to do.  There's no node_modules checked in with our code, so I'm trying to run "npm install" to generate for this existing project.

Comment: @GopakumarGopalan Yes, I've done that, many times.  Same results every time.

Comment: what about the  node_modules visible in the attached image?

Comment: @Andy It seems like you are trying the right things. Have you tried these in an administrator console?

Comment: have you tried deleting the package-lock.json? also as @R.Richards said, are you running as admin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and removing the package-lock.json and running npm install solved it for me.

Answer (score 7):

First Clean the cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then Install It

```
npm install
```

Answer (score -4):

It is actually very simple. Just do a `sudo npm install node_modules` if you are using Mac/Linux or just a `npm install node_modules` on windows.